# Output all lines from file that are not present in piped input to grep

Tags: shell, grep

I would like to get a list of Atom packages that are **not** installed, comparing to a fixed list of packages stored in `packages.txt`:

```
highlight-selected@0.11.1
ruby-block@0.3.5
```

To get a list of packages that are installed, I use `apm list --installed --bare`:

```
highlight-selected@0.11.1
```

So, I would get the `ruby-block@0.3.5` package, since that is the one listed in `packages.txt` and not installed.

I tried something like:

```
apm list --installed --bare | grep -v -f packages.txt
```

but it doesn't work. How should I tweak my command to achieve what I want?

Comment: From your comment on the answer, it looks like your "doesn't work" means it doesn't print any lines. You should edit that into the question.

Comment: And that means you probably have a blank line in the file.

Comment: No, the suggested solution does not work :)

Comment: ok, then what do you mean by "doesn't work" in the original question?

Comment: And still check for an empty line.

Comment: It doesn't output anything. I've checked for empty lines, removed them, but the issue persists.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to know the packages listed in the file that don't appear in the apm list output.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-v` prints the lines in the input that don't match any pattern in the pattern file. You want the inverse, lines in your file that don't match the input. The way to achieve this is to switch the input and pattern. You also need to remove any blank lines from the output:

```
grep -v -f <(apm list --installed --bare | sed '/^$/d') packages.txt
```

Ex:

```
% cat packages.txt
highlight-selected@0.11.1
ruby-block@0.3.5
% cat installed
highlight-selected@0.11.1
% grep -vf installed packages.txt
2:ruby-block@0.3.5
```

That should work on all greps; gnu grep should let you use stdin as the pattern file directly:

```
apm list --installed --bare | sed '/^$/d' | grep -v -f - packages.txt
```

Comment: I see no difference from the other answer, which I already stated it doesn't work for me...am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't look closely enough at that one. This works in my tests, so there's something wrong on your side or something you're not telling us.  Save the apm output into a file and check it for empty lines.

Comment: Indeed, the `apm` command outputs a new line at the end...how can I get rid of it?

Comment: @AndreiHorak pipe it through either `sed '/^$/d'` or `awk 'length($0)'`

Comment: It indeed works. Thanks for helping and for suggesting the empty lines!

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to keep the *piped output* as temporary file, such as with the following syntax:

```
$ grep -v -f <(apm list --installed --bare) packages.txt
```

Comment: It does not work for my example, it returns nothing. If I remove the `-v` flag, it matches everything from `packages.txt`.

Comment: Ahh, I guess you wanna match the entire line, then. You should use the flag `-F`, that stands for fixed strings. It holds the match considering the entire line as pattern.

Comment: It's the same with the `-F` flag on. I also checked and removed empty lines, as suggested in another comment.